# Predicting percentiles (or standard deviation) with a DNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

We are using a DNN (with Keras and Tensorflow) to predict a value `y` based on some data `X`, which works quite good. Now we’d like to extend that to not only predict the value `y`, but also its distribution in the form of percentiles.

An example: say we are dealing with house prices. A specific real house (with data `X’`) is currently sold for 1 million, so `y(X’) = 1 000 000`, but we know that this is a high price. We estimate that 90% of all comparable houses (houses with the same `X’`) are sold cheaper, so the 90th percentile of `y(X’)` is at 1 million.

How can we use our dataset `(X,y)` to train a DNN to predict/estimate that the 90th percentile of `y(X')` is 1 million?

In a way, such a network does not just learn with which values it can minimize the cost function, but also how big the noise is at which input. As another example, let's say that we have a certain `X'` at which the house prices are constant at 100 000 $ (for example because of some state-run program which builds thousands of exactly equal houses which all sell at exactly 100 000). I want the network to not just learn the value of 100 000, but also that this is a very exact prediction.

I think if we could predict the standard deviation, we could calculate a reasonable percentile distribution, so maybe the standard deviation is enough.